# troubles working on a script with $# and a loop

Tags: shell-script

i have the following script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++));
    do
       if [ ! -d $i ]
       then
          echo $i its not a directory >> file.txt
       else
          DIRECTORY=$(ls -l $i | grep ^d | wc -l)
          LINK=$(find $i -type l | wc -l)
          FILE=$(ls -A $i | wc -l)

          echo `date "+%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%y"` directory $i file count: $FILE link count: $LINK subdirectory count: $DIRECTORY >> file.txt

       fi
    done
```

this script count the subdirectories, links and files from a directory entered by parameter(it can be more than 1).

i am struggling with the loop, it returns "echo $i its not a directory" reading $i as 1 instead of $1, i do understand why it does that but i am starting with scripts and don't know how to fix this. i think a "while" can be a substitute for that "for" but don't know how to use it properly.

thanks for the help!

Comment: just tried it, returns "$i is not a directory"

Comment: You're never actually looking at the arguments themselves, just numbers from 1 to _n_ (where _n_ is the number of arguments), and testing those numbers and not the filenames you think you're testing.

Comment: i saw that, but i didn't have a clue on how to solve it, ill have to work harder on scripts, thanks.

Comment: As mentioned, you can use indirection (`${!i}`) also, but in your case, just looking at the arguments themselves (`$@`) is simpler.

Comment: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Use `find` instead.  e.g. `DIRECTORY=$(find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name '.*' -print0 | sed -z -n -e '$='` (requires a recent GNU sed for the `-z` option).  and use something similar for symlinks (`-type l`) and regular files (`-type f`).   The `! -name '.*'` excludes hidden dot-files/dirs from being counted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping from 1 to [number of arguments], and then testing if each of those numbers is in fact a directory.  It might be simpler to do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
for item in "$@"; do  # iterate over the arguments themselves
    if [[ ! -d "$item" ]]; then
        echo "$item is not a directory" >> file.txt
    else
        DIRECTORY=$(ls -l $item | grep ^d | wc -l)
        LINK=$(find $item -type l | wc -l)
        FILE=$(ls -A $item | wc -l)

        echo `date "+%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%y"` directory $item file count: $FILE link count: $LINK subdirectory count: $DIRECTORY >> file.txt
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is called variable indirection—you want to refer to the variable whose *name* is stored inside another variable.  This is possible in `bash`—just refer to `"${!i}"` instead of `$i`.

Also note the [importance of double quotes around your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943).

That said...you can simplify your script drastically.  For instance, [here is a one-liner](https://superuser.com/a/623594/504387) that does nearly everything you are trying to do with your script.

Comment: +1. that one-liner in the `else` clause of @dopeghoti's bash script (and run `date ...` before the one-liner) would be good.  and move the `>> file.txt` to the end of the `done` line.